# Does PostgreSQL PDPG support Yakkety (Ubuntu 16.10)?

Tags: postgresql, installation, ubuntu

The official repository does not have [Yakkety (16.10 packages)](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/). It seems it stops at Xenial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL's PDPG only creates separate packages for LTS releases, however it seems to suggest that it *should* work in the [FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#I_am_using_a_non-LTS_release_of_Ubuntu)

> I am using a non-LTS release of Ubuntu
>   Non-LTS releases of Ubuntu are only added to the repository if the packages from the latest LTS release are incompatible with the release in question. Using the latest LTS release instead generally works, unless library dependencies cannot be fulfilled, in which case we will provide updated packages for the non-LTS release.

I'm a little hesitant to spring for *generally* works, but there you have it.

So do *not* run the suggested command,

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Instead, run

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Warning, I wasn't not able to get this to work... Installing postgis failed.

```
 postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3 : Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
                              Recommends: postgresql-contrib-9.6 but it is not going to be installed
```

Ubuntu 16.10 does not ship with [`libgdal1i`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgdal1i), it ships with `libgdal20` and `libgdal-dev` which uses 2.1.1. [Bug filed here](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2100)

Comment: This has just been resolved by the addition of zesty (17.04). Sorry for the lack of earlier response.